# 2D color plot using a limited dataset

Tags: matlab, plot

I couldn't find a solution after trying for a long time.

I have 3 columns of data:  `x`, `y`, and the stress value (`S`) at every point `(x,y)`. I want to generate a 2D color plot displaying continuous color change with the magnitude of the stress (`S`). The stress values  increase from `-3*10^4 Pa` to `4*10^4 Pa`. I only have hundreds of data points for an area, but I want to see the stress magnitude (read from the color) at every location `(x, y)`. What Matlab command should I use?

I want to make a 2D color plot showing stress magnitude (`S`) at every location `(x, y)` based on continuous color change using limited data points

Answer (score 2):

I'd use [patch](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/patch.html) with interpolated coloring:

```
% some data, x/y are random
N = 50;
x = rand(N,1);
y = rand(N,1);
S = sin(2*x)+y;

% plotting
tr = delaunay(x,y);
trisurf(tr,x,y,zeros(N,1),S,'FaceColor','interp');
view (2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [`surf` and `mesh` in the MATLAB documentation](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/learn_matlab/creating-mesh-and-surface-plots.html)

Answer (score 0):

To further contribute on Gunther Struyf answer; assuming it is a FEM analysis you may already have a connectivity matrix say 'M' and 'x' 'y' column vectors with node coordinates. Stress values at the nodes may be contained in a column vector 'S'; then you may use the patch function as stated above:

> patch('faces',M,'vertices',[x(:) y(:)],'facevertexcdata',S(:),'FaceColor','interp');

and you will have a 2D plot of your data similar to the one posted by Gunther Struyf.